# Как сделать редирект с одной страницы на другую?

Tags: .htaccess, url, чпу

Из

> /1/2/3/avtomobil-mercedes?f=1&Itemid=114

в

> /avtomobil-mercedes

Можно и посредством *.htaccess*

Answer (score 0):

`.htaccess`

При условии, что в пути всегда будет 4 слеша:

```
RewriteRule ^[0-9a-zA-Z_]+/[0-9a-zA-Z_]+/[0-9a-zA-Z_]+/([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)$ /$1
```

Comment: Не работает....

Comment: Я у себя проверил - работает, а какую ошибку пишет ?

Comment: ошибку никакую не выдает, как работало, так всё и осталось без изменения

Comment: Можете привести ваш .htaccess файл ? Возможно, что другие правила влияют на это правило

Comment: RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)(/)$ $1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^[0-9a-zA-Z_]+/[0-9a-zA-Z_]+/[0-9a-zA-Z_]+/([0-9a-zA-Z_]+)$ /$1

Comment: Добавьте
RewriteEngine On в начало файла